# Open Port for home server on router

Tags: router, dmz

I want to access home web server from internet. At last I could do by enabling my DMZ and pointing host to Local IP. My router configuration does not show up port forwarding. But  I understand that making it DMZ the whole system is exposed  to internet which is  not  safe.

So my question is: how do I open only one port on my router?

Comment: What's the brand and model of your router?

Comment: You should provide a bit more info than this, like Kenneth told, you should at least give us your brand and model of your router.

Answer (score 0):

As you've given little info I'll post the generic answer:

1. Go to http://portforward.com/
2. Search for Brand
3. Search for model
4. Pick http/https
5. Follow instructions

A DMZ isnt terrible, but you want to know what you're doing or you could well be compromised quite quickly.

There is the possibility that the router you have is ISP branded and the feature has been turned off. It could also be listed as a subheading of NAT.

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I  have  gone  through port forward. My internet  setup is  through Alcatel Lucent modem/router which is connected to  primatel wireless router.

Comment: If the forward is entered correctly and it doesnt work then you need to check: A. Firewall on Alcatel isnt set to ignore forwards (Medium to low for example), B. The listener is actually active (does localIP:80 give you access from the same network?) and C. The host OS's firewall isnt blocking the WAN traffic, it usually will by default.